# laravel eloquent create without fillable attribute

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, request, laravel-5.4

this is my model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\BaseModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class Domain extends BaseModel {

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name', 'username', 'password', 'plan', 'payment', 'status', 'duration'];
    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    protected $rules = [
        'user_id' => [
            'required',
            'integer',
            'exists:users,id'
        ],
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'regex:/^(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])$/i',
            'unique:domains,name',
        ],
        'username' => [
            'sometimes',
            'nullable',
            'min:1',
            'max:16',
            'unique:domains,username',
        ],
        'password' => [
            'sometimes',
            'nullable',
            'min:0',
            'max:65',
        ],
        'plan' => [
            'sometimes',
            'nullable',
        ],
        'payment' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:40',
            'in:webpos,cheque'
        ],
        'status' => [
            'sometimes',
            'nullable',
            'integer',
            'in:0,1',
        ],
        'duration' => [
            'sometimes',
            'nullable',
            'integer',
            'min:1',
            'max:10',
        ]
    ];

    protected $attributeNames = [
        'user_id' => 'Domain Sahibi',
        'name' => 'Domain Adı',
        'payment' => 'Ödeme Şekli',
        'status' => 'Domain Durumu',
        'duration' => 'Domain Süresi'
    ];

    public function setUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        if ( is_null($value) ){
            $value = str_random(16);
        }
        $this->attributes['username'] = strtolower($value);
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        if ( is_null($value) ){
            $value = str_random(16);
        }
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

    public function setPlanAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['plan'] = strtolower($value);
    }

    public function setNameAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['name'] = str_replace('www.', '', $value);
    }

    public function setStatusAttribute($value)
    {
        if ( is_null($value) ){
            $value = 0;
        }

        $this->attributes['status'] = (int)$value;
    }

    public function setDurationAttribute($value)
    {
        if ( is_null($value) ){
            $value = 1;
        }

        $this->attributes['duration'] = $value;
    }
}
```

this is my controller :

```
$req = $request->only(['user_id', 'name', 'payment', 'status', 'duration']);
$result = $this->domain->add($req);
```

bu i got this error

> "Invalid Request SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `domains` (`user_id`, `name`, `payment`, `status`, `duration`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, deneme-1.com, cheque, 0, 1, 2017-07-03 13:58:03, 2017-07-03 13:58:03))"

why is the username and password go to the sql ?

i added these to fillable array. i can't figure out it why didn't work it ?

i don't want that username and password come with request . i want to set default str_random. but not wokring ?

where is the problem ?

and is it the right way to set the default attributes for null come attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by replacing:

```
$req = $request->only(['user_id', 'name', 'payment', 'status', 'duration']);
```

with:

```
$req = array_merge($request->only(['user_id', 'name', 'payment', 'status', 'duration']), ['username' => null, 'password' => null]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you put **'username'** in the variable **$fillable** var 
and your **column** in your DB must be
    **nullable()** .